# C# Assembly.Load with reference dlls

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I am using the following code to load dlls at run time, and store their classes for later use.

```
public LoadDll(byte[] data)
{
    Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.Load(data);
    System.Type[] types = loadedAssembly.GetTypes();
    TypeRepo.Register(types);
}
```

and this works great, but if the dll I built has reference to another dll I get the error "The classes in the module cannot be loaded." when calling GetTypes().

How can I provide a specific file path to allow the loaded assembly accesses to a dependency on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should play with [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx)

See what *remarks* section of the linked documentation points out:

> It is the responsibility of the ResolveEventHandler for this event to
>   return the assembly that is specified by the ResolveEventArgs.Name
>   property, or to return null if the assembly is not recognized. The
>   assembly must be loaded into an execution context; if it is loaded
>   into the reflection-only context, the load that caused this event to
>   be raised fails.

So you need to perform an [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx) to return the whole `Assembly` instance by loading satellite assemblies from an arbitrary path defined by you in code.